# The word "have"

Tags: word-meaning

"I have them all memorized"

I thought have is used when something is done by someone and the subject tells them to do so.

Like : "I had my computer fixed"
"I had my hair cut"

So what's the meaning of "have" in "I have them all memorized"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a slight extension of the usual meaning of "have" meaning .possession.

> Do you have the tickets?
>
> I have them all in my bag.

This refers to literal possession, and the phrase "in my bag" indicates the state of the tickets (specifically the location)

> Do you have the answers?
>
> I have them all memorised.

By slight extension, you can possess an answer in you memory.

Comment: See also the definition 1b in https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/have -- *have (something) to do, finish (etc.)*.